# How to retry async aiohttp requests depending on the status code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using an API and sometimes it returns some odd status codes which could be fixed by simply retrying the same request. I am using aiohttp to do submit requests to this api asynchronously.

I am also using the backoff library to retry requests, however it appears that requests are still not being retried upon 401 status responses.

```
   @backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, aiohttp.ClientError, max_tries=11, max_time=60)
    async def get_user_timeline(self, session, user_id, count, max_id, trim_user, include_rts, tweet_mode):

        params = {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'trim_user': trim_user,
            'include_rts': include_rts,
            'tweet_mode': tweet_mode,
            'count': count
        }


        if (max_id and max_id != -1):
            params.update({'max_id': max_id})

        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(self.access_token)    
        }

        users_lookup_url = "/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"

        url = self.base_url + users_lookup_url
        
        async with session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers) as response:
            result = await response.json()
            response = {
                'result': result,
                'status': response.status,
                'headers': response.headers
            }
            return response
```

I would like all requests to be retired up to 10 times if the response has a status code other than 200 or 429.

Comment: How about using a `for` loop?

Comment: @spectras i use this library because of the backoff strategy.

Answer (score 24):

I made a simple library, that can help you:
https://github.com/inyutin/aiohttp_retry

Code like this should solve your problem:

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from aiohttp_retry import RetryClient

statuses = {x for x in range(100, 600)}
statuses.remove(200)
statuses.remove(429)

async with ClientSession() as client:
    retry_client = RetryClient(client)
    async with retry_client.get("https://google.com", retry_attempts=10, retry_for_statuses=statuses) as response:
        text = await response.text()
        print(text)
    await retry_client.close()
```

Instead `google.com` use your own `url`

Comment: How do you use this when having many URLs, and using asyncio.gather?

Answer (score 21):

By default aiohttp doesn't raise exception for non-200 status. You should change it passing `raise_for_status=True` ([doc](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession)):

```
async with session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, raise_for_status=True) as response:
```

It should raise exception for any statuses 400 or higher and thus trigger `backoff`.

Codes 2xx shouldn't be probably retried since these [aren't errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success).

---

Anyway if you still want to raise for "other than 200 or 429" you can do it manually:

```
if response.status not in (200, 429,):
     raise aiohttp.ClientResponseError()
```

Comment: but how can we retry the request which got either 502 or 504 by using the above approach?

Comment: @Kulasangar you could use the aysnc_retrying library for that https://pypi.org/project/async_retrying/

Comment: Thanks for the input @Akhil

Answer (score 3):

Mikhail's answer cover how to raise exception for status codes 4XX and 5XX, but if you want your coroutine to be retried for these status codes, take a look at `async_retrying` library - https://pypi.org/project/async_retrying/

A simple example is given below.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from async_retrying import retry


@retry(attempts=2)
async def hit_url(url, session: ClientSession):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        print("Calling URL : %s", url)
        await response.text()
        return response.status


async def main():
    urls = [
        "https://google.com",
        "https://yahoo.com"
    ]
    api_calls = []
    async with ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
        for url in urls:
            api_calls.append(hit_url(session=session, url=url))
    await asyncio.gather(*api_calls, return_exceptions=False)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too old, but for any people wondering how to build such solution

RequestData and ErrorResponseData are your custom classes, it's not something built in

```
class DataAPI:
    def __init__(self, api_data_converter: APIDataConverter):
        self.api_data_converter = api_data_converter

    async def _bound_fetch(self, request_data: RequestData, session):
        try:
            async with session.get(request_data.url, raise_for_status=True) as response:
                return ResponseData(await response.text())
        except aiohttp.ClientConnectionError as e:
            Logging.log_exception('Connection error: {}'.format(str(e)))
            return ErrorResponseData(url=request_data.url, request_data=request_data)
        except Exception as e:
            Logging.log_exception('Data API error: {}'.format(str(e)))
            return ErrorResponseData(url=request_data.url, request_data=request_data)

    async def _run_requests(self, request_data: List[RequestData]):
        for rd in request_data:
            Logging.log_info('Request: {}'.format(rd.url))
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=ClientTimeout(total=80)) as session:
            tasks = []
            for rd in request_data:
                task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._bound_fetch(rd, session))
                tasks.append(task)
            responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
            return await responses

    def get_data(self, request_data: List[RequestData]):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        skipped = request_data
        responses: List[ResponseData] = []
        for _ in range(2): # specify your retry count instead of 2
            interm_responses = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(self._run_requests(skipped)))
            skipped = []
            for resp in interm_responses:
                if isinstance(resp, ErrorResponseData):
                    skipped.append(resp.request_data)
                else:
                    responses.append(resp)
            if not skipped:
                break

        if skipped:
            Logging.log_critical('Failed urls remaining')

        for resp in responses:
            data = self.api_data_converter.convert(resp.response)
            if not data:
                Logging.log_exception('Data API error')
            dt = dateutil.parser.parse(data[-1]['dt'])
            resp.response = data
            resp.last_candle_dt = dt
        return responses
```